# How to check if a note has been played in a audio file

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to create a application that changes the color of lights depending on what note is played on a musical keyboard, I have got the light changing, but have no clue how to check if the note from the keyboard is the same as a pre recorded sound.

This is a simple diagram

Keyboard from audio interface -> Software -> Changes light color depending on the note

The software is just to check if a note has been played, if so, what note, and return a string for the second half of the software to change the light to.

If you press F# on the keyboard, it would make the lights turn red.

Comment: Assuming the keyboard is external, is it sending an audio signal or MIDI? If MIDI, you should be able to intercept and read the MIDI pitch field. If audio, you'll probably have to employ some sort of fourier analysis/spectrum analysis tool using an FFT.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner It's a audio signal, thanks for the help.